# Cannot add meta tags with React 18.2.0

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, meta-tags, react-helmet

Hi I've done a couple of projects in React but I am new to adding meta tags in React. I have tried the plugin `react-meta-tags` which doesn't work and have tried `react-helmet` which also doesn't work and get the following error in console:

> Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode is not
> recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See
> https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.
>
> - Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.
>
> Please update the following components: SideEffect(NullComponent)

On searching this error it seems I cannot use react-helmet but instead should use `react-helmet-async`.

Unfortunately the examples of how to use it doesn't match my code at all so cannot get it working.

My pages are basically:

```
Index.js
App.js
|_ Home.js (/)
|_ Page1.js (/page1)
|_ Page2.js (/page2)
```

Here is my code so far:

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {Route, Routes, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Page1 from "./pages/Page1";
import Page2 from "./pages/Page2";
import NoMatch from "./components/NoMatch";
import React from "react"

function App() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <>

                    <button onClick={(e)=>{navigate('/');}} >
                        Home
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={(e)=>{navigate('/page1');}} >
                        Page1
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={(e)=>{navigate('/page2');}} >
                        Page2
                    </button>

        
        <Routes>

            <Route exact path={'/'} element={<Home />} />

            <Route path={"/page2"} element={<Page2 />} />

            <Route path={"/page1"} element={<Page1 />} />


            {/*####   404 #####*/} 
            <Route path={"*"} element={<NoMatch />} />
        </Routes>
        </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js, Page1.js, Page2.js are all identical apart from the names that are changed:

```
import React from "react"


const Home = () =>{


    return(
        <>
            hello from Home
        </>
    )
}
export default Home
```

Over at the docs page for react-helmet-async the usage example is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Helmet, HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';

const app = (
  <HelmetProvider>
    <App>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.tacobell.com/" />
      </Helmet>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </App>
  </HelmetProvider>
);

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  app,
  document.getElementById(‘app’)
);
```

But I have no idea which page that is supposed to go on or where in my code it is supposed to go. I do not know what their "App" is referring to and I do not have an element anywhere with an id of "app". I have tried applying this code to all of my pages and just get errors.

Does anyone know how to get this working or any other way to get meta tags (titles and meta descriptions) working with the current version of React please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/669), `react-helmet` is not maintained and has some issues with react-18. Here's a partial solution to your issue. This is what I use to dynamically update the title of the page.

```
const usePageTitle = (title) => {
  const defaultTitle = "app-name";

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = title || defaultTitle;
  }, [defaultTitle, title]);
};

function Demo() {
  usePageTitle("Demo");
  return <h1>Demo</h1>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After searching all day your solution is much appreciated. The react-helmet-async just seemed impossible to understand with my set up. I don't know why I couldn't find a solution as simple as yours. With a bit of tweaking I was able to use it with the meta descriptions as well.

Comment: Awesome, glad that helps. Would you mind sharing how you tweaked it to update meta tags?

Comment: Ok just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version based on @Moath's answer that addresses both page title and meta description:

```
const usePageMeta = (title, description) =>{
    const defaultTitle = "app-name";
    const defaultDesc = "meta description";

    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = title || defaultTitle;
        document.querySelector("meta[name='description']").setAttribute("content", description || defaultDesc);
    }, [defaultTitle, title, defaultDesc, description]);
};

function Demo() {
  usePageMeta("Demo Page Title", "Demo meta description");
  return <h1>Demo</h1>;
}
```

Comment: While this script doesn't rely on there being a default or empty title in place to begin with for it to set the title, it does require there to be a default / empty meta description in place as it is attempting to find it and replace the content attribute. Perhaps there's a cleaner method than to use document.querySelector...setAttribute?

Comment: the problem with react18 is the SSR rendering of meta information. currently, there is no solution for dynamic content. gatsby can be used for reference for static head and tags.